How to remove associated observation from 2 datasets in r
I have a complex filter I am trying to implement but not sure how to make it work.
I have two datasets:
data_1 <- data.frame(
ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4),
speciale = c(80003, 80003, 80003, 80004,  80004, 80005, 80005, 80006, 80005, 80003),
week = c("0109", "0110", "0111", "0212", "0209", "0209", "0309", "0309", "0310", "0311")
)


data_2 <- data.frame(
ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4),
speciale = c(80001, 80001, 80001, 80001, 80001, 80001, 80001, 80001, 80001, 80001, 80001, 
80001),
week = c("0109", "0109", "0110", "0111", "0212", "0212", "0209", "0209", "0309", "0309", 
"0310", "0311")
)

data_1 dataset has some ids, which have some specific identified codes in the variable "speciale" which are associated with the "speciale" codes in data_2 dataset.
What I would like to achieve is to exclude any observations from data_2 that matches the ID and week variable from data_1. That means that I want to associate each row from data_1 with only one row in data_2 and remove only one of the observations in data_2 that match ID and week number of data_1 dataset.
For example for ID = 1 in data_1, data_2 has two exact observations for week "0109" and for the week "0209" and I want to keep only 1 of those records and remove only one of them. (In my actual dataset data_2 might have 3 observations in total that match the one observation in data_1 and I still want to keep the two observations in data_2 and only remove 1 from it.)
On the contrary, for ID = 2, ID = 3 and ID = 4, in data_1, both of the associated observations from data_2 should be removed because each of these two observations in data_1 have two observations in data_2 dataset that match.
I do not want to use distinct() on data_2 because my real dataset is more complex than this small example.
Desired output:
 ID  speciale  week
  1   80001    0109
  1   80001    0212

Thanks.

What is the result you expect from the input data you have provided?

Instead of describing your desired output, it would have helped if you showed your desired output.

Thanks and apologies. I have added a desired output now

You can try adding a temp_id by ID and week in both data frames, then anti_join() by those three variables:
library(dplyr)

data_2 |>
  mutate(temp_id = row_number(), .by = c(ID, week)) |>
  anti_join(data_1 |>
              mutate(temp_id = row_number(), .by = c(ID, week)), join_by(ID, week, temp_id)) |>
  select(-temp_id)

  ID speciale week
1  1    80001 0109
2  1    80001 0212


Thank you very much! it worked great in my data! I appreciate the help!
